# Can I access my DirectAdmin files from MS Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-development-server, directadmin

At the moment I am using DirectAdmin (giving by my web-hoster) where I upload and edit my website's files. It is a bit of a schlep using their online UI.

Am I able to access the files on DirectAdmin via MS Visual Studio Code directly from my computer? It would make debugging and updating the site tremendously easier.

I have looked up this question. It seems there are plugins for Visual Studio that can do this. But I do not know the process behind SSH. I do not know what steps to follow. All the guides online are complicated. Also, none of them address the settings I have to change on DirectAdmin for this to work.

I have only been designing websites for a few years, and my knowledge of the webhosting system behind it is very slim. This is the only place I could ask.

In short, I need to know if this is possible, and what steps I need to follow on Visual Studio and on DirectAdmin.

If you could help I would be extremely grateful.